# Retrieve large attachments sent a while ago in Gmail over Google Drive

Tags: gmail, google-drive, attachment

About a year and a half ago, I sent an e-mail from Gmail with a large .ZIP archive (~90MB). Because the attachment was too large for Gmail, it offered to send it by creating a link to Google Drive.

So, I send that e-mail, and the recipient got it and downloaded that archive from Google Drive.

Now, a year and a half later, I need that archive with pictures, but misplaced it somewhere on my laptop, and the recipient does not have those pictures either.

I found the e-mail in my Sent folder in Gmail, clicked on archive.zip, and got the following message:

Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.
Make sure that you have the correct URL and the file exists.

My question is: Is it possible to somehow retrieve that archive.zip with pictures (is it saved anywhere on Google Drive) or is it gone forever?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [Restore a user's Gmail and Drive data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340?hl=en) Google support webpage, you can't restore data that was permanently deleted more than 25 days ago. After 25 days the deleted data is gone forever.

Comment: @dim4x4 If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.